# Java restTemplate and response charset

Tags: java, response, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I am having some troubles using restTemplates.

I am posting some JSON and I expect some plain text as a response.

I wrote some code to do so, but the response I am getting is not readable (栀琀琀瀀猀㨀⼀⼀愀眀猀甀愀琀　㄀⸀ as an example.)

When I use PostMan with the following setup:

[image: PostMan1]

and passing my JSON I get the text I am expecting with the following response:

[image]

The below is my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders(token);
            
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("test", test);
            
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(json.toString(), headers);
try
{
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URI, entity, String.class);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Error handling
}
```

Where the headers are:

```
return new HttpHeaders() 
{
    {
        String authHeader = "Bearer " + token;
        setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
        add( "Authorization", authHeader );
    }
};
```

By using the above I do get a 200 response code but with a non readable body. Looking at my logs I can see that the actual request was done with:

```
URI         : MyURI
Method      : POST
Headers     : {Accept=[*/*], Content-Type=[application/json], Accept-Charset=[big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp], Authorization=[Bearer Bearer], Content-Length=[X]}
Request body: {"test":"test"}
```

It seems that even though I am explicit asking for a response in UTF-8, the request itself is asking for a response with all the possible Charsets and I am keen to believe this is why I cannot read the response.

Furthermore I can see that the response I am getting is in UTF-16:

Status code  : 200
Status text  : OK
Headers      : {Date=[Sun, 23 Jan 2022 21:03:49 GMT], Content-Type=[text/plain; charset=utf-16], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive]}

Any help on this?